# setBounds in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I'm trying to convert a Objective-C app to Swift but I'm stuck with `setBounds`. The original code looks like this:

```
- (void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds {
    [super setBounds:bounds];

    // code
}
```

What is the equivalent in Swift? I've tried looking in the documents and google but can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: `bounds` is a property of UIView. What's your issue, what have you tried?

Comment: the files are here: https://github.com/fastred/CustomScrollView . I've managed to convert most of the code but the original code in Objective-C seems to be overriding the method `(void)setBounds:(CGRect)bounds`. Here I'm stuck and don't know what I should override in Swift.

Comment: `super.bounds = bounds`?

Comment: I'm kinda confused right now. Should I override the property `bounds` like: `override var bounds: CGRect { didSet { } }`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to override `bounds`:

```
override var bounds: CGRect{
   didSet{
          //your code here  
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I was really confused. Can't accept till 4 min so I'll accept the answer when I'm back!